# Docker container exits immediately after DOCKER RUN command

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, lxc

Please do not ignore this, I have tried to go through the other solutions proposed on the forum and none solved my problem.

I am kick-starting with Docker and the DevOps stuff. Started with the basic get-started tutorial on their [page](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app). I am unable to run the application as described in the tuto,

```
$ docker --version  
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

I am running docker on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, the following are the different verifications i did

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
friendlyhello       latest              cb003cf9993a        6 minutes ago       194MB
python              2.7-slim            451c85955bc2        7 days ago          182MB
hello-world         latest              1815c82652c0        6 weeks ago         1.84kB

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
7d094e902b93        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     7 minutes ago       Exited (0) 7 minutes ago                       awesome_fermi
9d358777b84d        hello-world         "/hello"            3 hours ago         Exited (0) 3 hours ago                         eloquent_euclid
```

I noticed that actually when i run an application, the `Status` is `Exited` as shown above.

```
$ Curl http://localhost:4000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused
```

The content of the `Dockerfile` is show below:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Comment: Check the logs of your application, `docker logs CONTAINER_ID`

Comment: Check logs and post error and if app.py is a small file then post that too. But I believe just the error messages should be good enough to help you out